# Constrain view to UIBarButtonItem custom view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create an overflow menu similar to what is seen on Android in the navigation bar. Here is an example:

[image: Android Overflow Menu Example]

I've done this by creating a UIView that is hidden unless a particular button is clicked. This is all working fine but the issue is constraining the overflow menu to the button.

Within the overflow menu, I am attempting to constrain the overflow menu to the button (this button is a custom view of a UIBarButtonItem):

```
topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor).isActive = true
leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

I receive the following error:

```
UIButton:0x7f84974081e0.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.
```

How can I position a UIView relative to a navigation bar button item custom view?

**Notes:**

1. For some reason, the UIBarButtonItem's custom view is not a descendant of the view controller **but** UINavigationBar is?
2. Attempted similar idea with a popover but failed to reliably control the position of the popover. It seems iOS has firm control over where it is positioned
3. Can manually make the overflow menu frame equal to button frame but I am having trouble reliably detecting when the button frame changes. KVO seems like the best method but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Im not sure you can put a view on top of standard navigation bar. And YES, button and view are on different superviews so you cannot add auto layout like this. try adding constraint (top) to self.view with negative constant value, but I thing it will go under the navigation bar.

Comment: I just tried this and it did put my view on top of the navigation bar. However, I constrained the view for one view and if I move to a different view size, the offset changes. This feels hacky to hand specify the constraints based off distance from the top-right corner of the screen.